# How to Resize ListView control when resizing window

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, autoresize

I have a user control that holds a ListView within a grid.
But my problem is that if i maximize my applications window the ListView dimension (Height) does not change relative to the window. It always keeps the same height. In this case 200 as defined below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModuleLogger.Views.ViewLogger"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Log Entries" Style="{StaticResource myLblStatHeaderSmallStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />
        <ListView x:Name="lvLogs"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Log Entry" Width="810">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Entry}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<Style x:Key="myListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

The user control itself is used within a tabitem.

```
<TabItem Header="Log" Name="tabLog" BorderBrush="LightGray" Style="{StaticResource myMainTabItemStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl Name="RegionLog" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionLog" Grid.Column="0"/>
</TabItem>
```

I have tried to change my RowDefinition to

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="15" />
     <RowDefinition Height="30" />
     <RowDefinition Height="15" />
     <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This approach solves my problem. But it brings me to another problem. In this case i dont get a vertical scrollbar. So the ListView becomes "endless" and you can just see the top entries.

Is there a way to define the Grid//ListView so that the ListView automatically resizes if the window resizes?

Comment: The code you pasted here works fine and does what you want (with star height). The problem could either be in the style "myListViewStyle" or in the XAML outside the part you pasted. We need to see more code to be able to help you.

Comment: @Eirik:I have updated the question and added the entire UserControl as well as the related ListView Style. Maybe this helps. THX

Comment: The code still works as intended here. Where is the UserControl placed? Look through the Visual Tree and check if there are any controls that allow content to grow outside the viewable area, such as a StackPanel, that contains the UserControl.

Comment: The usercontrol is used within a tabitem as i updated. Could it be caused by the tabitem? how can i prevent the tabitem to let my usercontrol expanding in that way?

Comment: Check further up the Visual Tree. If the TabControl is within a StackPanel it could also lead to what you're experiencing. Check the Visual Tree all the way to the top and try to determine if there is a control that allows the content to grow outside the viewable area.

Comment: @Erik: I checked it. It should be ok. On top is a grid. but I think i found the problem [here](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/03/18/itemscontrol-vs-listbox-vs-listview-in-wpf/). The key is: **ItemsControl takes as much space as it needs for its child elements**, which can cause it to be larger than the screen. Because its size is based on its child controls, ItemsControl does not resize when re-sizing the screen. So my problem is caused by the items control. Now i have to find out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i could solve the problem.
The key is the information from following [link](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/03/18/itemscontrol-vs-listbox-vs-listview-in-wpf/): **ItemsControl takes as much space as it needs for its child elements, which can cause it to be larger than the screen. Because its size is based on its child controls, ItemsControl does not resize when re-sizing the screen.**

So the following xaml part was causing the problem.

```
<TabItem Header="Log" Name="tabLog" BorderBrush="LightGray" Style="{StaticResource myMainTabItemStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl Name="RegionLog" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionLog" Grid.Column="0"/>
</TabItem>
```

Instead of using a ItemsControl I use a **ContentControl**.

```
<TabItem Header="Log" Name="tabLog" BorderBrush="LightGray" Style="{StaticResource myMainTabItemStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContentControl Name="RegionLog" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionLog" Grid.Column="0"/>
</TabItem>
```

So my ListView just expands to the maximum size that is given by the ContentControl.

Maybe that helps somebody in the future who runs into the same problem.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant by "any controls that allow content to grow outside the viewable area". I just missed that you had an ItemsControl in there..oh well, good thing you solved it :)

Comment: Thx for your help. Your questions/hints guided me to the solution. I just wanted to answer it here so that anybody else has a quick solution.